# How do frameworks such as AngularJS route requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

Many web frameworks such as AngularJS support "routing" whereby the user can visit the website, and have a template displayed to them based on their request URL.  But these frameworks are entirely frontend JS, just simply a 'script src' import, so how does it manage to capture all requests to the website, and then redirect to a js file for processing, etc.

Any response is appreciated, since I have been trying to work out how exactly these frameworks execute the 'capturing' part of routing for some time, but with no luck.

Comment: Are you asking how exactly the framework internally handles the routing once the files have been served by the back-end? Or how the back-end "gives control" to the front end? for example, when developing an spa and serving the files in node.js, all routing can be handled with something like:

`app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './build', 'index.html'));
});`

is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a simple model for it.

We can grab the current URL. We can then break that string and we can get different parts separated by '/' Based on which we can put condition which page and what data to show. And when we have decided that we can load our desired page using ajax.

For example my current url is https://www.example.com/module I can get "module" out of this url and then I can load inside the body of my page

```
$('body').load('module.html');
```

The following code is from my current work. See how different urls are captured and routed to my specified document. I also get the data from url to use into my ajax requests etc.

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl : "home.html"
    }).when("/logout", {
        templateUrl : "logout.html"
    }).when("/course/:id", {
        templateUrl : "course.html"
    }).when("/course/:courseId/assignment/:assignmentId", {
        templateUrl : "assignment.html"
    });
});
```

Comment: How about `https://www.example.com/sub/dir/module`? How is this hitting `https://www.example.com/index.js`, and not `https://www.example.com/sub/dir/index.js`?

Comment: Again its upto us how we design the routing system for us. In such applications there is only one entry point. That entry point manages the routing it does not matter what url you pass.

Comment: Check the edited post where I have URLs of different levels but they call the files from the root directory.

Comment: @AbdulAleemKhan You still haven't answered the question though, because what part of your code means that when a user visits the webpage, it runs 'index.js' and doesn't try to run a file/directory named 'module'. How does it override that default behaviour.

Comment: That is the part of server @LuckyBowers. That depends on how a server will handle its url. Either it will go to a directory or it will make a route for it. If you have any idea about .htaccess file we can redirect any request to a single page or anywhere else by typing in some rules in it. So if the server allows to a url to open a directory then that is how that specific server is written. While writing node or angular route we specify the behavior manually.

Comment: I have been using htaccess, etc. for over a year now, very experienced in it @AbdulAleemKhan but AngularJS is simply a javascript file, so it doesn't use backend redirection like that.

Comment: The thing is the ngRoute module makes it happen. ngRoute makes the deeplinking of location.url() and route possible. If you will try to land on a page directly with its url then ngRoutes wont be activated. For example. If example.com/module opens the page module.html via route then if I will open example.com/module.html then it will open this file and and no routing will happen. In the case where you dont give absolute path to a file ngRoute will take over as it watches location.url.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute start from this link it will give you a general idea.